# Is suggestions for music instrument going to be considered offtopic

Tags: discussion, support

Is suggestion for music instrument or price range of music instruments will be considered off-topic?

Like I want to buy a very specific guitar for a specific style(in my case its fingerstyle, with budget constrain)

or

I want to by a microphone, that don't cause an extra zzzzz noise.

Asking what are my choices, is this question is going to be off topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So-called "shopping list questions" [are off-topic](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/are-shopping-list-questions-on-topic), but there might be ways to make your question more general -- e.g., "what should I pay attention to when looking for specific guitars if I want to play this particular kind of music". The second question will be more appropriate [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/), but I would rephrase it as something along the lines of "how do I setup my recording equipments so as to avoid those noises" (I'm not sure what zzzzz refers to or what the proper term for that is, so I'd encourage you to be more specific).