# Why is my post about getting a music producing software off topic?

Tags: discussion, software, closed-questions

You can read [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5895/which-windows-software-can-i-use-to-create-music-for-aerobic-exercise-programs) my question. It take me a long time to write it, because i want to make my point clear. I did link some examples and created a demo and uploaded it to make my point clear! So the quality of question is in a high state...

I did read the FAQ and it says:

> Musical Practice and Performance - Stack Exchange is for musicians,
>   students, and enthusiasts. Topics include practice & performance,
>   composition, technique, theory, and history. "Listening
>   recommendations", song identification, and shopping recommendations
>   are off-topic.

so after this definition my question is on topic! because i do not ask about a shopping recommendation, i am looking for a software to remix music. **To produce music to fit my aerobic lessons.**

like [Matthew](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/28/matthew-read) said:

> "Shopping recommendations are off-topic, whether software or other.
>   Software questions such as "How can I do X in program Y?" are
>   on-topic"

so you did not get my question!

```
X = music mixing for aerobic music schema 
Y = in any software which can support that
```

**I do not know which software can do that! So I am asking for it.** Not like others who want to compare different types of software. **I really have no clue!**

I think my question is equal to this one:
[How can I get that flanger effect from "The Pretender" by Foo Fighters?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4503/how-can-i-get-that-flanger-effect-from-the-pretender-by-foo-fighters)

Because he has no clue how he can receive this special effect. I have no clue how i can produce my music in this way. If he does not have this effect he will buy it, and so do i... I know this isn't 100% comparable but it should give an impression of how i am feeling.

Also [Luke](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/1678/luke) agrees with me to be on topic.

*I'm also sad about the down-voting on a well formatted post with a clear question structure and a big description without commenting... But this happens in other stackexchange network sites too...*

I'm writing here, because I want my post be re-opened again! Because I really need an answer if someone had similar problems and could tell me how he made it. Or someone has the experience and can tell me which software could solve my problem...

Or I want to have a better description why my post is unbearable in this context of Site.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I see some relations to [this Meta SU Question](https://meta.superuser.com/q/2088/119634).

See the answer below this Question:

> Shopping suggestions will be closed almost every time.

okay

> For example, instead of asking what's the best product a better question would be "What technology should be considered when purchasing product. For example, I wanted to know about laptop batteries since mine died. I didn't now want to know about which was better than the other, but rather give me the information as to waht to look for in a good battery.

and that is my point. I'm not interested in the best software. I am interested if there is such software! I mean for sure there have to be some, but i do not know it and want to know some... I'm asking here to get help to find some... Because if I am unable to name my software or can get information about the type here, i can't google etc. for it...

> This is the main root, in my opinion, as to why shopping questions are so strictly monitored and closed. These type of questions bring no growth to the OP or the general public, but is rather just "fluff" that Super User and Stack Exchange will not be a part of.

And that is what i think my question is not about. Maybe i did not found the right description in a foreign language but i think my question brings a growth! Because I do know many people who are looking the same way and do not know where they can ask such a question... and if they would find answers with different software and (this was something i was really whishing) can link to sources with tutorials for my need, than others is helped too...

Comment: this sort of question is open to opinion and wouldn't have a definitive answer in the end because there are multiple software suites available for music production

Answer (score 7):

I'm sorry you spent so much time on that question only to have it closed. When you're new to an SE site, it usually pays to lurk for a little while and answer some questions while getting a feel for what questions are on-topic before asking one of your own.

No matter how much supporting material you provide, the nut of the question was still "What software should I buy?", so I agree that @Matthew was correct in closing as shopping-rec. One important rationale for this is that SE questions should be enduring, or future-proof, and helpful to people who search the question later. In 2 years, there could be a completely different software landscape, and any answers that helped at the time you asked would be irrelevant to the future viewer.

I would also guess that some of the downvotes are related to the clarity of the question itself. It's very broad, and not quite clear if you just want to burn the tracks that you already have to CD, actually produce brand-new tracks from scratch, or something in-between. Also, some of the supporting material you provide is not really relevant--the different ways in which 32-bar segments can be put together is not going to dictate your software decision. (There is no Automagick Workout Music Creator™, to my knowledge.)

The best way to ask this question would be to pick one of the specific problems you face in its most basic form, figure out if it fits one of the SE sites, and *then* post a question on the appropriate site (after a thorough search, of course).

The problem of "I need to burn gapless audio CDs!" might be a good fit for [A-V Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/).

The problem of "I need to produce new aerobic exercise music!" might manifest itself as "What style characteristics exist in aerobic exercise music?" on [Musical Practice and Performance](http://music.stackexchange.com), but I think it's clear you're already quite the expert on that!

The problem of "I need to pitch and adjust tempo on some audio tracks in Cubase." might be a good fit for AVP.SE *or* Music.SE.

The problem of "I don't know what software to buy!" *isn't a music problem*, and as such, is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: +1 for being the first who gives me an answer I can live with. Although I do not fully agree with. If I ask something about IE 6 it gets also outdated! Or jQuery 1.4 or whatever has to do with software in my opinion. Like I said I can partly agree with you. And I did not know something about [A-V Site](http://avp.stackexchange.com/). For me it is a confusing jungle of sites and if someone of the downvoters have said it is something you have to post there, i wouldn't post here this objection on meta. Because If someone says I am off topic then i want to know his arguments! Like you did now.

Comment: Well, IE version 6 or jQuery version 1.4 is going to be exactly the same in 10 years. An answer might not be relevant to newer versions of that software, but it will still be relevant to people who have to work with those older versions. That's why it's okay to ask questions about specific pieces of software on this site.

Answer (score 5):

Just like Stack Exchange doesn't have site for every conceivable topic, the sites that *do* exist don't cover every conceivable question related to their primary topic.  As you've already found, we don't do shopping questions; you'll have to go elsewhere for that kind of advice.

You can see here for some detail on why they're off-topic: [Are Shopping List Questions On-Topic?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/are-shopping-list-questions-on-topic)

Your question definitely isn't of the how-do-I form, and please note that while shopping questions are pretty much off-topic on all SE sites, SU's particular application of that rule doesn't apply to sites other than SU.

Comment: okay so if i write "How do I create music cds for aerobic exercise" it will not be closed and i get software as answers? Sounds a little bit hypocritical.

Comment: @Neysor A question that solicits shopping recommendations as answers is still a shopping question. You'd need to ask something specific; there are endless ways to create CDs.