# Is it okay to ask about guitar buying guide?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are Shopping List Questions On-Topic?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/are-shopping-list-questions-on-topic)

Is it okay to aski about electric guitar buying guide and recommendation in a certain budget on this fourm?

Comment: We're not a forum -- check out the [FAQ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the FAQ](https://music.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), you can see that one of the off-topic items is:

- shopping or buying/selling recommendations