# Why don't we allow buying guide questions?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are Shopping List Questions On-Topic?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/are-shopping-list-questions-on-topic)

Continuing from this [question](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390/is-it-okay-to-ask-about-guitar-buying-guide), why don't we allow questions about buying guides for musical instruments? IMO to practice music you have to understand the specs of the instrument first and know what it can and can't do

Comment: We do want to give you the tools to evaluate instruments -- see [this question](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/1496/28) for example -- that you can evaluate for your own situation.  But we avoid lots of localized questions that are only suited to one person's situation and budget.