# Creating new content by asking & answering

Tags: discussion

I was reading meta questions and found [this](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/we-should-try-to-produce-more-expert-questions) one about "expert" questions. Because I want to cooperate, and I have a 5 year University Education in Violin, I asked [one](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11529/fingering-for-playing-three-octave-scales-on-the-violin/11530#11530) typical "medium advanced student" question about scales in the violin. I asked and answered. I have more and I think they would be good to have here but I feel for asking you guys:
Is it ok if I post 5-10 questions about violin "nerd" issues? will that help MPP (maybe by google search)?

I think if a violin OP comes here and sees violin related questions he will be interested, but it also feels strange of me to "manipulate" the tag an post&answer a bunch of questions.

Comment: I think we generally welcome self-answered questions. It can be nice to not ask them all at once, and to leave a question a day or so to see if anyone else has an answer, but generally, if it may help others, I say go for it.

Answer (score 6):

Seeding sites with questions is generally discouraged.  If it's not a problem you've actually faced, or not something that will be useful to others, please don't post it.

In particular, do not post questions in order to increase any sort of site stats.  If you feel you could be more proactive in involving our site in your own normal research in problem solving, that's different :)

Otherwise, Dr Mayhem's comment applies.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion Mathew. Yes, I mean questions that were a problem for me sometime in my development. I think that if "some" question exist here both new users will feel this might be the right place for them to ask question and they will find MPP easier by "googling" that question, what do you think about that?

Comment: Self-answered questions still have to follow the same guidelines as regular questions - but if you think they do, go for it!